# .NET / C# Usb communication library

Tags: c#, usb

Possible duplicate: How do you get a list of all usb devices connected to your machine. And if it is possible to debug incoming data from a specific usb device. how?
Note: I'm not talking serial connections, i got those figures out. But devices such as the Logitech G502 mouse, uses not serial communication, yet still manages to talk to their software on the pc.

No serial listed on the G502, how to communicate with it.
[G502 mouse properties image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quoFP.png)

Comment: You need to install generic winusb driver to comunicate with WinUSB API

Comment: USB is always serial at the hardware level.  Device specific drivers sometimes convert the serial data to other type of interfaces.  Microsoft has a standard mouse interface so a mouse USB driver will take serial data and make it look like a mouse interface.  A USB interface will have type and manufacturer so you can get all the USB devices by type.